# spring example with wrong datasource configuration

Tags: spring, jpa, configuration, jboss, datasource

I try to run the example project of jboss-springmvc-webapp, but I fail to configure the data source.

the error is:

```
JBAS014775:    New missing/unsatisfied dependencies:
  service jboss.jdbc-driver.mysql (missing) dependents: [service jboss.data-source.jboss/datasources/SpringQuickstartDS]
```

my persistence.xml is:

```
<persistence version="2.0"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
 <persistence-unit name="primary">
  <!-- If you are running in a production environment, add a managed 
     data source, this example data source is just for development and testing! -->
  <!-- The datasource is deployed as WEB-INF/spring-quickstart-ds.xml, you
     can find it in the source at src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring-quickstart-ds.xml -->
  <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/SpringQuickstartDS</jta-data-source>
  <properties>
     <property name="jboss.entity.manager.factory.jndi.name" value="java:jboss/spring-quickstart/persistence" />

     <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop" />
     <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" />
  </properties>
</persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

my datasource.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<datasources xmlns="http://www.jboss.org/ironjacamar/schema"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.jboss.org/ironjacamar/schema http://docs.jboss.org/ironjacamar/schema/datasources_1_0.xsd">
<!-- The datasource is bound into JNDI at this location. We reference 
  this in META-INF/persistence.xml -->
<datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/SpringQuickstartDS"
  pool-name="kitchensink-quickstart" enabled="true"
  use-java-context="true">
<connection-url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testdb</connection-url>
<driver>mysql</driver> 
  <security>
     <user-name>root</user-name>
     <password></password>
  </security>
</datasource>
<drivers>
    <driver name="h2" module="com.h2database.h2">
            <xa-datasource-class>org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource</xa-datasource-class>
    </driver>
            <driver name="mysql" module="com.mysql.jdbc">
                <xa-datasource-class>com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlXADataSource</xa-datasource-class>
            </driver>
            <driver name="postgresql" module="org.postgresql.jdbc">
                <xa-datasource-class>org.postgresql.xa.PGXADataSource</xa-datasource-class>
            </driver>
        </drivers>
</datasources>
```

Comment: also solve with https://zorq.net/b/2011/07/12/adding-a-mysql-datasource-to-jboss-as-7/

Answer (score 0):

If you use the jboss-springmvc-webapp architype then it should come configured to use H2 as a datasource.  I would go back to that configuration first to confirm that it works.

Then when you know everything else is working you can set up a MySQL datasource.  There are 2 things you need to know.  You can only point to one datasource at a time, so you must remove the other ones from the file above.  It can only have the MySQL info (if that is the datasource you are using).  Second, you will need to make sure you have the JDBC driver for the database that you are going to use.

Every version of JBoss has good docs on setting this up.  What version of JBoss are you using, I'll post the doc page?